# Google Analytics (G4) - Internal Traffic as Dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

How can I use the Internal Traffic as a Dimension in my reports?

So I set up internal traffic on my GA4 Google Analytics which works great.
Now in my data filters currently my filter is set to "Testing" which allows me to already do what my end goal is, but in an ugly way.
With Testing selected I will now have a dimension called "**Test data filter name**" and a dimension value called "**Internal Traffic**".

The other option is setting the filter to active which would do the following:
*This filter will be evaluated and applied to incoming data. Matching data will be excluded from processing.*

I don't want this. I want to effectively include matching data and use them in my reports.

Is there any way to have a proper dimension for internal traffic?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative solution for you. However, in my unsolicited opinion cases like this are a great reason _not_ to use GA4 yet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how / if you can do it in GA4 as I do not use it. However in Universal GA you can accomplish this by leveraging query parameters and a user-scoped custom dimension.

Here's a guide: [Simple Way to Exclude Internal Visits From Google Analytics](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/simple-way-exclude-internal-visits-google-analytics/)

> With Google Tag Manager, you can take this query parameter and send it as a User-scoped Custom Dimension to Google Analytics.
> You can then create a view filter that excludes this particular Custom Dimension from your main reporting views, or you can use segments to identify the traffic in the reports.

### Alternatively, You Could Send Internal Traffic Data to a Separate GA4 Property

This is probably a cleaner approach.

1. Set a cookie that returns true for internal users (e.g. `_is_internal`)
2. Create a lookup table variable that outputs the measurement ID for your separate GA4 property
3. For your *input* enter "true" and for your *output* add your measurement ID e.g `G-XXXXXXXXX`
4. In the *default value* field put your existing measurement ID
5. Modify your GA4 Configuration tag entering `{{lookup - measurement id}}` in the *Measurement ID* field.

If the traffic is *internal* your cookie var will return true and the tag will output the measurement ID for your new property designated for internal traffic. Else, it will return your default measurement ID.

Lastly, you will have to modify your GA4 Configuration tag